# Difference between running bash script

Tags: bash, curl, sh

What is the difference between running scripts like this?

```
curl -L https://url.com/install.sh/script | sh
curl -L https://url.com/install.sh/script | bash
```

And

```
curl https://url.com/install.sh/script > install.sh && sh ./install.sh
curl https://url.com/install.sh/script > install.sh && bash ./install.sh
```

EDIT: the reason I'm asking is that the first method gives me syntax errors, the second method works just fine.

Comment: If you're getting errors, it would easier to get help if you tell us what the errors are.

Answer (score 2):

You're using two different mechanisms of Unix shells here:

- `|` is a pipe, it passes `stdout` of one process on to `stdin` of another process; thus, when executing your first command, you're downloading content which gets printed to `stdout` with `curl`, then you execute `sh/bash` with that downloaded content on its `stdin`
- `>` is a redirection, it places `stdout` of a process in the file following the operator (in your case `install.sh`); then, another command is called (they are combined with a logical `&&`, i.e. the first command must exit with a success status) which calls `sh/bash`, but this time with that exact file as their input

Usually, one would assume that both methods are achieving the same thing.

Comment: thats what i was thinking too, but yet again i get syntax errors when using pipe, and no errors when using >

Comment: Can you provide the actual URL you're making the request to or is the install script confidental? I think without seeing that script (or at least the error messages you get), it's hard to find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the script is passed directly to the shell (sh/bash) during the download and executed without being placed on a hard disk/SSD beforehand.

Comment: the reason I'm asking is that the first method gives me syntax errors, the second method works just fine.

Comment: The second variant has the advantage that the script is only executed if curl was able to download the script completely.

Comment: Why are you/are you not providing the `-L` option to `curl`? Could that be causing your error? You should [check if you need that option or not](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L).

Comment: same thing even without -L